# Deduping data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query the shows only the non duplicate values, I am looking for a solution on how to use this deduped data in other queries.

I do not have permissions to create anything, so i need to find a solution for that.

IDAN

EDIT (from "answer"):

this are the fields in my table "Purchases": user_id purchase_amount purchase_sku source device_type uuid - a unique identifier for each row

duplicate is considered when all fields except the uuid are identical. i need to return deduplicated data and prepare it for use for other queries.

this is the basic data, with duplicated values in rows 5-6 and 7-8

i want to show to non duplicate rows ,and on the duplicated row show only one row,like this:

deduped data

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you mean by "non duplicate values".

Answer (score 1):

Consider below generic solution - you do not need to enlist all the column names at all - only uuid is used in query)

```
select any_value(t).*
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by to_json_string((select as struct * except(uuid) from unnest([t])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qualify` with `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from purchases p
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id, purchase_amount, purchase_sku, source, device_type order by uuid) = 1;
```

You can also use aggregation:

```
select purchase_amount, purchase_sku, source, device_type,
       min(uuid) as uuid
from purchases
group by 1, 2, 3, 4;
```